# как поднять элемент выше?

Tags: html, css

```
HTML:

        <div id="block-about">
           <div class="about-product">
                     <p>About your product</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="disc">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis facilis fuga, illo at. Natus eos,</p>
                    <p>eligendi illum rerum omnis porro ex, magni, explicabo veniam incidunt in quam sapiente ut</p>
                    <p>ipsum.</p>
                    <p>Pariatur iure ab sunt nesciunt, quibusdam odio iste cumque itaque, ipsa vel exercitationem</p>
                    <p>ullam quos aut nostrum cupiditate fuga quaerat quam animi dolores. Sequi itaque, unde per-</p>
                    <p>ferendis nemo debitis dolor.</p>
                     <div class="video">
                         <img src="video.png">
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

СSS:

```
.disc{
margin-top: 40.032px;
margin-left: 40.032px;
}
.disc p{
    font-size: 21.412913px;
    font-style: regular;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #333333;
}

.video{
    padding-top: 40.032px;
    right: 40.032px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 6;  
   }
```

элемент "video" ниже, чем надо. Выровнять с помощью padding и margin не вышло. Как выровнять элемент выше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "video" ниже, чем надо

а как надо? Рисунок в студию.

паддингами вы его не выравняете, т.к. паддинги - это отступы ВНУТРИ него.

отрицательный маргин сам по себе не поможет, т.к. если элемент упирается в границы другого, то дальше он не полезет. Но поможет при абсолютном позиционировании.

float тут в принципе лишний.

а еще есть свойство `transform:translate(x,y)`. Попробуйте его.